# Expand an existing class, with additional functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

How can I expand an existing class, with additional properties, methods, or functions? So that I can use them in the XAML code?
I would like to extend the AlavonDock library and add more functionality to the existing classes.

That's precise what I mean:
The AvalonDock.dll should to contain, in class LayoutItem a further Property: SubTitle.
I wouldn't like to edit the existing classes (in the AvalonDock library). But I want to create my own dll which extends the functionality of AvalonDock.dll.

Comment: Wrap their classes in yours, and implement whatever methods and properties that you wish.

Comment: Depending on the classes you want to extend; Inheritance, Encapsulation, Decorator pattern, Proxy pattern could all be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the relevant class like you would any other class:

```
using AvalonDock; // or whatever the dll is called

public class ExtendedClass : OriginalClassToExtend
{
    private string subTitle = string.Empty;

    public ExtendedClass() : base()
    {
        // Add new functionality to constructor
    }

    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Please take a look at the [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) page on MSDN for more help.

Comment: can I initialize an `ExtendedClass` instance based on `OriginalClassToExtend` instance? Add SubTitle  and return?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'initialize an `ExtendedClass` instance based on `OriginalClassToExtend` instance', but this follows all the polymorphism rules that any extended class follows. Therefore, you could cast an `OriginalClassToExtend` instance to an `ExtendedClass` instance and set the `SubTitle` property on it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own class that derives from `AvalonDock` classes and add whatever functionality as you would like

```
public class MyLayoutItem : LayoutItem
{
    public string SubTitle 
    {
         get { return (string)this.GetValue(SubTitleProperty); }
         set { this.SetValue(SubTitleProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SubTitle", typeof(string), typeof(MyLayoutItem),new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: I have created an example with an app and two libs.  My wrapper class, in the second dll, inherits from a class in the first lib.  In XAML of the app, I try to create an element of the second class: <sc:WrapperClass/>. This can not be instanciated, but the class in my second lib have not a ressource that in first lib (usercontrol) was have identified

Comment: This is the original message: The component "ThemeEarthLibrary.ADWrapper" does not have a resource that is identified by the URI "/AvalonDock;component/yellowedit.xaml".

Comment: @peter70 What is your xmlns of `sc`?